# Why doesn't JSON tolerate trailing commas after the last element?

Tags: json

Why doesn't JSON tolerate a trailing comma after the last element?

```
[
{
    "id": 1,
    "username": "john"
},
{
    "id": 2,
    "username": "william"
}
]
```

Be it a comma after the value "John" or be it the second JSON user object, why is JSON not tolerating the comma? Don't we have a simple engineering solution that can solve this tiny problem and by the way we are in the "Deep Learning" era. I am more curious to know why does it exist.

Comment: Javascript is OK with that, but JSON says no. It's not that we couldn't, it's just that is what the specification says. *shrugs*

Comment: `¯\_(ツ)_/¯` ask Douglas Crockford. Most things in computing ... well, most things in life, frankly ... aren't that way because the other way is impossible, just because somebody decided not to do it, or even just that they didn't think about it.

Comment: Because it's a seperator. You don't practice your way in English either: `John, Jenna, and Jacob,`, you write `John, Jenna, and Jacob`.

Comment: A lot of good points [here](https://devrant.com/rants/3918250/why-doesnt-json-allow-trailing-commas-why-how-hard-is-that-to-implement-everyone) namely:  
**1** Commas a meant to be delimiters of data, think about `'1,,3,'.split(',')` would return empty values requiring more complexity to implement. **2** Similar point, trailing commas are just a lazy syntax for devs. **3** The json spec is not meant to be written like other programing languages, nor is it meant for configs but rather a a simple data transfer format. Not my words just ideas :)

Comment: It is because "Commas are delimiters, not terminators"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> An array structure is represented as square brackets surrounding
> zero    or more values (or elements).  Elements are separated by
> commas.
>
> array = begin-array [ value *( value-separator value ) ] end-array
>
> There is no requirement that the values in an array be of the same
> type.

[RFC 7159 section 5](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159#section-5)

Effectivly, trailing commas are not allowed as defined by the specification.

There are linting tools which will automagically fix it for you, but it's usually a sign you've done something wrong.

Comment: Eh, "because the spec" says so doesn't really answer the question. Trailing separators are acceptable in many other contexts, so why was the JSON spec written this way?

Comment: This does answer the questions posed. You're looking for the answer to the question: Why was the json spec designed to forbid trailing commas. A different question entirely .